# Properties or methods or both?

Tags: c#, .net, coding-style

In .NET libraries and also in many third-party libraries, I can see that there is some convention in how to change the internal (private) member values, they support Properties (.NET Properties) or methods (these are commonly used in java as Setters and Getters) or both for programmers.

I wonder when (and why) using Properties, methods, or both. For example, the visibility of a control can be changed using either **Visible** property (in Windows Forms) or call to method **Show()** or **Hide()**. There are some values (I understand that there are some internal/private values) which can be changed only via calls to methods (like setters). When designing my own controls, classes I'm a little hesitative to choose Properties or methods (or support both?), in fact, choosing either is also OK (Java is an example which uses only methods). I know the advantage of Properties over methods (as getters and setters) but if so why do we have to use methods in some cases, they are presented to the programmers or even replace properties. I'm a bit confused at this, and for me (as I said), I feel OK when using only methods (like as I do in java, it's not so bad :).

I would like to know your experience and also your convention on this to follow. I like following standard conventions in programming (for each programming environment and each language) to differentiate between them. Not like some ones who invent their own styles which are a little illegible to other programmers such as using C++ naming convention (even PHP naming convention?) in C#? a little weird to me, sorry.

Please share, thanks...

Comment: If a public properties and class implement iNotifyPropertyChanged then the UI is dynamically updated.  Voting to close.  There is a lot on msdn on this.

Comment: @Blam, you are talking about UI? UI is only one of many cases, there are tons of classes especially in the world of open source and third party libraries which are not UI-related and doesn't seem to follow any convention. They even use methods many more than properties.

Comment: So what is your point?  Yes you will find a lot of code that uses no convention.  Your question is tagged .NET and you asked when and why.  I gave one example of when and why you would use a property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know the advantage of Properties over methods (as getters and setters) but if so why do we have to use methods in some cases, they are presented to the programmers or even replace properties.

In general, there is an expectation when using a class that a property will be "fast" and have no side effects.  A method, on the other hand, suggests that "something" is going to happen.

When choosing whether to expose an API based on a property or a method, I'd try to look at what the value/method/etc represents.  If it's a *value*, and can be directly returned (or fetched very quickly with little side effects), then a property makes more sense.  If it's an operation, then a method makes more sense.

Comment: Well, yes an operation is really easy to realize if it is for doing something else except 'set/change some private value', as I said, I'm focusing on setter methods only not general methods. The operation of setter methods is in fact to change some value and this can be done by using property instead.

Comment: @KingKing Yes, and I'm saying that, if there is a side effect (some operation occurring) that's long running, etc, then a method makes this more clear.

Comment: OK, look like that I should try understanding more about side-effect. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To take your example: setting the Visible property to false does not immediately hide the control--the property does not contain any code or call any code that hides the control; instead it changes the state of the control, so that later on it will be hidden (by other code). In contrast, a Hide method will hide the control immediately; the Hide method contains code or calls code that actually hides the control.

Setting Visible to false might hide the control (almost immediately), but this is because there is other code running which detects that the state of the object has changed (the Visible property has changed) and responds immediately by actually making the control invisible.

I am talking in a general sense here without reference to any actual code library; it is perfectly possible to code a Visible property so it actually does hide the control, but that breaks the usual convention that properties do not have side effects.

So, properties change the state of the object, whilst methods actually do something (which may or may not change the state of the object).

Comment: great, thanks for the good answer, however for Visible property, as I have experienced, the control is hidden right after Visible being set to false. In fact, I've used Visible for a very long time before knowing/using Hide/Show method, and now I still use Visible more frequently than Hide/Show methods and everything is OK (the effect is reflected immediately not simply changes the states)?